# Is it alright to reapply to a PhD program you got rejected from if you work on your application?

Tags: phd, application

The main weakness in my application was my weak research experience in the field I applied to. Say I got two new writing samples and greatly improved my research experience. Would it be acceptable for me to reapply to a school I got rejected from? I really want to go to that program.

Comment: Which country are you applying to? What do you mean by writing samples? In several countries a "writing sample" doesn't count at all for the application, unless it is a published paper.

Comment: see http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/29094/are-there-any-restrictions-on-applying-to-the-same-graduate-school-in-two-consec?s=2|0.3945 and http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/47733/academically-dismissed-from-grad-school-but-want-to-reapply and http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/5445/reapplying-to-same-phd-program-after-one-year-should-i-state-i-applied-the-prev?rq=1

Comment: If you have evidence to show that you greatly improved your research experience such as you have published papers, then yes, it's alright to re-apply. I don't think new writing samples is enough unless they are peer-reviewed papers.

Answer (score 0):

Generally **yes** (with improvements). Consider emailing their admissions to make sure they don't have a policy against reconsidering applicants some time later.

Answer (score 0):

I would reapply if you feel you have a better chance. It's definitely worth checking with the university to find out their admission policies for re-applicants. For example, I know of a university in the UK that automatically reject re-applications from candidates without even considering their CV or interview. Doesn't make much sense to me.